# How can I add panels to the sidebar on the Document tab in Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I know it's possible to add panels to blocks using the editor.BlockEdit filter, but is it also possible to add additional panels to the "Document" tab to add some panels for post metadata?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845266/how-to-add-new-panel-under-document-in-gutenberg