# Prevent wp.hooks.addFilter() from Running on Certain Custom Post Types in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have been tasked with preventing `addFilter()` from running on certain custom post types using the new Gutenberg API and not any WP PHP. It's currently fed into the `editor.PostFeaturedImage` hook, meaning it fires every time the Gutenberg editor loads the Featured Image box.

The Filter calls a function that adds a dropdown menu underneath the featured image box to allow users to pick a contributor (which are themselves custom post types) to credit the image to.

The filter should not run on the contributor custom post type, but should run on other custom post types. There should still be a featured image box for the contributor custom post type, but no dropdown.

Letting the hook fire and then canceling within the function works but the function itself is resource heavy and the directive is to prevent the function from firing at all. The idea being that the built-in hook/function would fire instead.

[Borrowing from this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597095/how-i-can-add-a-custom-control-to-a-page/56635042#56635042), I attempted to place the main function `setFeaturedImageArtist` within an anonymous function that also printed the post type to console in `addFilter()`. I was able to get the post type to print, but calling `setFeaturedImageArtist` function didn't work as expected.

```js
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.PostFeaturedImage', 'blocks/featured-image-artist', function() {
    console.log(wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType())
    return setFeaturedImageArtist()
});
```

Placing `setFeaturedImageArtist`in a wrapper function like so didn't work either. I'm assuming it's because it's the same thing.

```js
function checkPostType() {
   console.log(wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType())
   return setFeaturedImageArtist()
}

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.PostFeaturedImage', 'blocks/featured-image-artist', checkPostType);
```

Here is the component the filter is triggering:

```js
function setFeaturedImageArtist( OriginalComponent ) {
  return ( props ) => {

    const artistSelect = compose.compose(

        withDispatch( function( dispatch, props ) {
            return {
                setMetaValue: function( metaValue ) {
                    dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost(
                        { meta: { 'featured-image-artist': metaValue } }
                    );
                }
            }
        } ),

        withSelect( function( select, props ) {
           let query = {
              per_page    : 20,
              metaKey    : '_author_type',
              metaValue  : 'artist'
            };

            let postType = select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType();
            if ( postType === 'contributor' ) {
                return null
            }

            // Please see below
            // if ( postType === 'contributor' ) {
            //  return {
            //     postType
            //   }
            // }

            return {
                posts: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'contributor', query ),

                metaValue: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )[ 'featured-image-artist' ],
            }
        } ) )( function( props ) {
            var options = [];

            // This works in removing the dropdown for authors/artists
            // if (props.postType === 'contributor'){
            //   return null
            // }

            if( props.posts ) {
                options.push( { value: 0, label: __( 'Select an artist', 'blocks' ) } );
                props.posts.forEach((post) => {
                    options.push({value:post.id, label:post.title.rendered});
                });
            } else {
                options.push( { value: 0, label: __( 'Loading artists...', 'blocks' ) } )
            }

            return el( SelectControl,
                {
                    label: __( 'Art Credit:', 'blocks' ),
                    options : options,
                    onChange: ( content ) => {
                        props.setMetaValue( content );
                    },
                    value: props.metaValue,
                }
            );
        }
    );

    return (
      el( 'div', { }, [
        el( OriginalComponent, props ),
        el( artistSelect )
      ] )
    );
  }
}

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.PostFeaturedImage', 'blocks/featured-image-artist', setFeaturedImageArtist  );
```

Here is the redacted component the filter is triggering:

```js
function setFeaturedImageArtist( OriginalComponent ) {
  return ( props ) => {

      const artistSelect = compose.compose(
          ...
      )( function( props ) {
          ... // Cancelling out here works, but resources are loaded by this point.
      });

      return (
          el( 'div', { }, [
              el( OriginalComponent, props ),
              el( artistSelect )
          ])
      );
  }
}

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.PostFeaturedImage', 'blocks/featured-image-artist', setFeaturedImageArtist  );
```

This is the [React error being received](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=):

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or
a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

I'm not sure what the best approach to this would be, and the documentation is scant/barely applicable. Is creating a custom hook that mimics `editor.PostFeaturedImage` but only fires on certain custom post types a possibility? Or is there some way to call a function like `setFeaturedImageArtist` within a wrapper that checks the post type?

- [Wordpress Hooks on Github](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/hooks)
- [Hooks in Wordpress Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-hooks/#api-usage)

Comment: I tested the *redacted component* without *artistSelect* and it works correctly. I think the issue might be in the fact that you are defining the component in the render function of the returned component. Try getting `artistSelect` outside.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Alvaro. Do you mean explicitly declaring a render function within `setFeaturedImageArtist` and then returning its value?

Comment: No problem at all. What I mean is that `artistSelect` is actually a component. So move it (cut+paste) outside of `setFeaturedImageArtist` and see if that helps. Or better, share its contents so its easier to help understading what its doing.

Comment: I'll try that now, thank you again! I've updated the component's content with the full code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate the script and fixed some issues:

```
const { createElement: el } = wp.element;
const { compose } = wp.compose;
const { withSelect, withDispatch } = wp.data;
const { SelectControl } = wp.components;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;

const ArtistSelect = compose(
    withDispatch(function(dispatch, props) {
        return {
            setMetaValue: function(metaValue) {
                dispatch("core/editor").editPost({
                    meta: { "featured-image-artist": metaValue }
                });
            }
        };
    }),

    withSelect(function(select, props) {
        let query = {
            per_page: 20,
            metaKey: "_author_type",
            metaValue: "artist"
        };

        return {
            postType: select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType(),
            posts: select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "contributor", query),

            metaValue: select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")[
                "featured-image-artist"
            ]
        };
    })
)(function(props) {
    var options = [];

    // This works in removing the dropdown for authors/artists
    if (props.postType === "contributor") {
        return null;
    }

    if (props.posts) {
        options.push({ value: 0, label: __("Select an artist", "blocks") });
        props.posts.forEach(post => {
            options.push({ value: post.id, label: post.title.rendered });
        });
    } else {
        options.push({ value: 0, label: __("Loading artists...", "blocks") });
    }

    return el(SelectControl, {
        label: __("Art Credit:", "blocks"),
        options: options,
        onChange: content => {
            props.setMetaValue(content);
        },
        value: props.metaValue
    });
});

function setFeaturedImageArtist(OriginalComponent) {
    return props => {
        return el("div", {}, [el(OriginalComponent, props), el(ArtistSelect)]);
    };
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "editor.PostFeaturedImage",
    "blocks/featured-image-artist",
    setFeaturedImageArtist
);
```

`ArtistSelect` is a component so we take it outside of `setFeaturedImageArtist` function. `withSelect` had a check for the `postType` that made it return null. Instead of that we pass that variable and then return null in the components render. An alternative would be to check inside `setFeaturedImageArtist`. This is a fixed version using JSX. Hope its clear:

```
const { compose } = wp.compose;
const { withSelect, withDispatch, select } = wp.data;
const { SelectControl } = wp.components;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;

const ArtistSelect = compose(
    withDispatch(dispatch => {
        return {
            setMetaValue: metaValue => {
                dispatch("core/editor").editPost({
                    meta: { "featured-image-artist": metaValue }
                });
            }
        };
    }),
    withSelect(select => {
        const query = {
            per_page: 20,
            metaKey: "_author_type",
            metaValue: "artist"
        };

        return {
            posts: select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "contributor", query),
            metaValue: select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")[
                "featured-image-artist"
            ]
        };
    })
)(props => {
    const { posts, setMetaValue, metaValue } = props;
    const options = [];

    if (posts) {
        options.push({ value: 0, label: __("Select an artist", "blocks") });

        posts.forEach(post => {
            options.push({ value: post.id, label: post.title.rendered });
        });
    } else {
        options.push({ value: 0, label: __("Loading artists...", "blocks") });
    }

    return (
        <SelectControl
            label={__("Art Credit:", "blocks")}
            options={options}
            onChange={content => setMetaValue(content)}
            value={metaValue}
        />
    );
});

const setFeaturedImageArtist = OriginalComponent => {
    return props => {
        const post_type = select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType();

        if (post_type === "contributor") {
            return <OriginalComponent {...props} />;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <OriginalComponent {...props} />
                <ArtistSelect />
            </div>
        );
    };
};

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "editor.PostFeaturedImage",
    "blocks/featured-image-artist",
    setFeaturedImageArtist
);
```

Comment: That did it! You're a treasure and a gem!

Comment: Whoops, spoke too soon on the import edit. This is perfect as is. Thank you again.